# send data to remote server with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an app, that generates a javascript code, which displays a widget on a website. When a data is submitted through the widget form, it posts the data to the server with a jQuery ajax function.

The problem is that I'm using a success callback that will never be fired if I place the widget on a website, which is on a different host. I know that its because javascript prevents cross-domain ajax and that I should use jsonp, but I'm wondering why success event isn't triggered, if the data is sent to the server normally?

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: report_url,
  data: $(form).serialize(),
  success: function() {
    alert("success called!");
  }
});
```

What would be the best way to do the same thing with jsonp? I'm a little confused if I should do it with jsonp and how, since it requires to define a jsonp callback parameter.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this using `JSONP`:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5CUk2/

*(Please check browser console)*

```
$(function() {

    //Example using flickr API
    var diffDomainUrl = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=mycallback&tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json';

    $('#jsonpbtn').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: diffDomainUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(data);
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'
        });
    });

});
```

---

By the way, you can try other possible "ways" to make a `cross-domain` request by taking a look to this, maybe can help:

http://usejquery.com/blog/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide